# How to get Cookies content from HTTP Request Header in CURL php?

Tags: php, curl, cookies

I need to get all cookie details from the http request header of an URL. How to get all cookies content using CURL PHP? Can anyone please help me.

Thank You!

Comment: You mean response header, right? You send the HTTP Request header, so you do already know what you send.

Comment: no. not response header. I need to load an URL with setting up session id, app_cookie etc. So I need these values from the request header to load the URL using CURL php

Comment: Then this doesn't make any sense. If you want to send cookies with your cURL request you already need to know what cookies you want to send. There is nothing to get.

Comment: Oh Can you please explain me how it should be done? I couldn't able to understand the concept. Thank You for your help charlotte

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$ch = curl_init('http://www.google.com/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
// get headers too with this line
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
// get cookie
preg_match('/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^;]*)/mi', $result, $m);

parse_str($m[0], $cookies);
var_dump($cookies);
```

Comment: preg_match('/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^;]*)/mi', $result, $m); deletes path and domain.